# Evaluating stream operator >> as boolean

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer

The following code compiles in Visual Studio 2008 but fails in Visual Studio 2013 and later.

```
std::string str("foo");
std::stringstream ss(str);
float f = 0;

if ((ss >> f) == false)
    std::cout << "Parse error\n";
```

The error message is

> error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'std::basic_istream>' (or
>   there is no acceptable conversion)

and is successfully fixed by changing as follows:

```
if (!(ss >> f))
    std::cout << "Parse error\n";
```

I'm not understanding this well. My question is, what operator or cast or maybe  `ios` flags are involved that allow the stream read to be evaluated as a boolean in the first place, and then why does the lack of an `operator==` break it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two behaviors changed since C++11.

1. **The behavior of [std::basic_ios::operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) changed.**

   ```
   operator void*() const;         (1) (until C++11)
   explicit operator bool() const; (2) (since C++11)
   ```

   Note since C++11 `operator bool()` is declared as `explicit`; but for `if ((ss >> f) == false)`, `ss` (i.e. the return value of `(ss >> f)`) needs to be implicit converted to `bool` (to be compared with `false`), which is not allowed.
2. **The definition of the null pointer constant changed.**

   Before C++11 `operator void*()` could be used and it's not `explicit` (before C++11 there's no such [explicit user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)), and before C++11 [the null pointer constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) is defined as:

   > an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero
   >   (until C++11)

   which means `false` could be used as a null pointer constant. So `ss` could be implicitly converted to `void*` and then compared with `false` (as the null pointer).

   From C++11, the null pointer constant is defined as:

   > an integer literal with value zero, or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`
   >   (since C++11)

   while `false` is not again; it's not an [integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

So, because of these two changes, `if ((ss >> f) == false)` won't work in C++11 and later.

On the other hand, `if (!(ss >> f))` works fine because there's [std::basic_ios::operator!](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) (both before and after C++11) for it.

> ```
> bool operator!() const;
> ```
>
> Returns `true` if an error has occurred on the associated stream.
>   Specifically, returns `true` if badbit or failbit is set in `rdstate()`.

BTW: Since C++11, even without `std::basic_ios::operator!`, `explicit operator bool() const` could also make `if (!(ss >> f))` works well, because in the context of [contextual conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions), `explicit` user-defined conversion is considered; i.e. `ss` could be contextually converted to `bool` for `operators !`.

Comment: Something worth mentioning is that `if(foo)` or `if(!foo)` works even if `operator bool` is marked `explicit` due to one of the few exception regarding explicit conversions for `bool` operators. Example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e884a7adaf92a472). I believe this is called **contextual conversion**, see e.g. [this blog post](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.ca/2013/07/contextually-converted-to-bool.html).

Comment: `NULL` is a macro that expands to *a* null pointer constant, not "the" null pointer constant, nor a synonym for the term "null pointer constant".