# Check the copy of contents into a file when using std:ofstream

Tags: c++, ofstream

I am trying to update some code and change a fopen() file operation with std:ofstream.During an fopen file operation fputs() is used to write contents into a fail.Checking the return of fputs ::(`fputs() return a nonnegative number on success, or EOF on error`). I need to check the copy of contents into the file.

This example is taken from  : [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/)

```
// ofstream::open / ofstream::close
#include <fstream>      // std::ofstream



int main () {

  std::ofstream ofs;
  ofs.open ("test.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);

  ofs << " more lorem ipsum";

  ofs.close();

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to find a way to check `ofs << " more lorem ipsum";` operation.Is there any kind of return of this operation?Does this throws something?

Warmest Regards.

Comment: You do not need to `ofs.close()` manually. The destructor of `std::*fstream` closes the linked file automatically.

Comment: I see, thank you @L. F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many operations on a stream, including the `<<` operators (in your case the non-member [`operator<<` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)), returns the stream itself. And the stream objects have [a boolean conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) that you can use in a condition to check if the stream is in a [good state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) or not.

For example like

```
if (ofs << " more lorem ipsum")
{
    // Output operation okay
}
```

This is most commonly used for input.

---

There's also the possibility to [set an exception mask](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) which will cause the streams to throw exceptions on specific states.

Exceptions are disabled by default.

Comment: Thank you.I have already check std::basic_ios, I don't feel really comfortable using this right now but I work on it.

Comment: I also believe that you info will help me to sort it out so it's marked like Solved.However if someone has any ideas, I'll be happy to review them.

Comment: Just for reference I copy this here, it might be useful as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564040/evaluating-stream-operator-as-boolean