# `ofstream` compared to 0

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, implicit-conversion, ofstream

I'm upgrading existing old code to use VS 2019<sup>*</sup>, in the code I have the following function that fails on the return line:

```
int foo(const char *fn) const
{
    ofstream out(fn,ios::binary);
    if (out)
    {
        //...
    }
    return out!=0;
}
```

The error I get is:

> Error  C2678   binary '!=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::ofstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

What was the original poet's intention, and what is the best way to fix the issue?

<sup>*This code compiles successfully on VS 2010.</sup>

Comment: There's a [conversion to bool](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/), so `return (bool)out != 0;` would compile. But that still seems nonsensical given that the function returns `int`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating stream operator >> as boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564040/evaluating-stream-operator-as-boolean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose with the upgrading, you're switching to C++11 mode.

Before C++11, [`std::basic_ios`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) (the base class of `std::basic_ofstream`) could convert to `void*` implicitly.

> Returns a null pointer if `fail()` returns `true`, otherwise returns a non-null pointer.

Then `out!=0` is checking whether the stream has no errors and is ready for further I/O operations.

Since C++11, there's only one conversion operator which could convert `std::basic_ios` to `bool`. Note that the operator is marked as `explicit`, so the implicit conversion isn't allowed for `out!=0`.

You can change the code to `!!out` (invoking `operator!`), or `!out.fail()`, or `static_cast<bool>(out)` (explicit conversion via `operator bool`).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `!out.fail()` to fit the other two?

Comment: @n314159 My fault. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two operators in the class `std::basic_ios` that can be applied in such a situation. They are

```
explicit operator bool() const; 
bool operator!() const;
```

So you can for example either write

```
return bool( out );
```

or

```
return !!out;
```

or

```
return !out != true;
```